# VBA: Setting a variable to a specific cell value

Tags: excel, vba, subscript

In **Sheet1** of my workbook, cell B2 has the value 29.

I want to assign a cell value to a variable, `num_g`.

I've declared `num_g` as Integer and am trying to assign its value with the code:

```
num_g = Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells(1, 2).Value
```

I'm using Cells() as I plan to replace the row with a counter.

However, I keep getting the "Subscript out of range" error (run-time error 9), and don't understand why.

How can I fix this? Declaring `num_g` as Long or String doesn't help, nor does formatting cell B2 as a number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the `!` in the sheet name.  vba does not use it.

Comment: God damn, I should have noticed that! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the "!" in the worksheet name:

```
num_g = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value
```

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions, instead vote to close them as typos.